# How to get Firefox to autofill passwords?

Tags: firefox, passwords

For whatever reason, on some sites Firefox autofills passwords, and one some sites it doesn't.

For instance, when I try to login to iCloud.com, I have to right-click on the password text box and select the login.

If there anyway to get Firefox to automatically fill in the password for sites that it knows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Frequently password managers / form auto-fillers use the underlying HTML tag names or IDs to determine what is a username or password field. It's possible that some of the sites you are visiting don't name the password field "password" and thus Firefox ignores them.

Try viewing the HTML one of the sites that Firefox is having a hard time auto-filling and seeing if there is an `<input>` tag with the name/id/type `password`

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to FireFox's **about:config** page.
Enter **signon.autofillForms.http** as the pref set and toggle it from false to true.

Comment: But why would password auto-fill work on some sites if this is set to “False”?

Comment: There is another pref **signon.autofillForms**, which by default is set to true. FireFox automatically fills in passwords in non-http sites (e.g. https).